# Commenting and Getting post information of other profiles using instagram graph API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is it possible

1. To comment on a public profile/page's post using Instagram graph API.
2. To get the comments information of a particular open profile? Like userid, username and their comments
   I have searched and went through the documentation on the facebook developers page and couldn't find it.
   Can I use anyother official APIs?